# destination with the same identifier (name{page.}) has been already used, duplicate ignored warning

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, fancyhdr, warnings

Consider this test case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{empty}{
   \pagenumbering{gobble}
}


\usepackage{titling}
\title{}
\author{}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\newpage


\textit{this page intentionally left blank}
\end{document}
```

It yields the warning:

```
destination with the same identifier (name{page.}) has been already used, duplicate ignored<to be read again> \relax l.24 \end{document} [2] (test.aux)
```

which presumably relate to a clash between `hyperref` and `fancyhdr` packages.

Is there any solution to fix this warning without loosing or disabling functionality?

An unrelated question: What is a reason, that `fancyhdr` breaks `empty` page style, so have to use `gobble` to make it work as expected? Can this be fixed by package options or something?

**UPDATE 1:**

Following *Pieter van Oostrum* and *Ulrike Fischer* suggestions, I dropped the use of `gobble` in favor of `\thispagestyle{empty}`, and it solved warning above. Thank you!

Unfortunately on a next step with defining style for main part of document (which goes after the ToC and prior appendices):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[headheight=30pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{stylemain}{
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
}

\usepackage{titling}
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\textit{this page intentionally left blank}
\newpage

\pagestyle{stylemain}
test
\end{document}
```

I got similar warning:

```
destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored<to be read again> \relax l.24 \end{document} [1] (test.aux)
```

I have to use `arabic` page numbering, since need to switch from `roman` used in ToC, so cannot drop it as `gobble` above. Can this warning be fixed without dropping `arabic`?

While looking on similar issues found `hypertexnames=false` option for `hyperref` package as workaround. It solves warnings for both test cases above without additional changes. But according to the `hyperref` documentation it is rather a hack to hide warnings, not to solve them. What are the consequences of its use while not solving warnings in essence?

Comment: It is not `fancyhdr`'s fault, but it is caused by your ` \pagenumbering{gobble}`. If you give this command and remove the `fancyhdr` stuff you get the same error. The reason is that the pdf identifier includes the page number which is empty because of your definition. So now you get two pages with the same identifier `page.` instead of `page.1` and `page.2`. So don't do that.

Comment: hypertexnames=false make it more difficult to guess the destination name "from the outside". Normally the anchor of section 1.2 will have the name `section.1.2`, with hypertexnames it will be e.g. `section.16`  with an unrelated number. You can also use pagelabels=false (if you don't have an index which should point back to pages).

Comment: You shouldn't add updates and new questions to an existing question. That can make answers invalid or give messy answers. Better create a new question about the arabic problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\maketitle` contains a `\thispagestyle{plain}` which overwrites the `empty` page style.

You can overwrite it by another `\thispagestyle{empty}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{titling}
\title{}
\author{}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage


\textit{this page intentionally left blank}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you have multiple pages with the same page number. Have a look:

```
\maketitle% <----------------------------------- page 1
% ...
\newpage

\textit{this page intentionally left blank}% <-- page 2
\newpage

\pagestyle{stylemain}% This resets the page numbering to arabic
test% <----------------------------------------- page 1
```

You can avoid this in a number of ways:

1. Since you don't want to print any page numbers around `\maketitle`, you could use any arbitrary page number for these two pages. For example, adding `\addtocounter{page}{-2}` before setting the `\maketitle` will put the title and subsequent page on pages -1 and 0, with the first actual page (containing `test`) start on page 1, as required, with no duplicate page numbers in use:

   ```
   \pagestyle{empty}
   \addtocounter{page}{-2}% To avoid duplicate hyperref links to pages with same page number
   \maketitle
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \newpage
   % ...
   ```
2. The above option might not be optimal, because the page numbers are often displayed in the output PDF. And seeing a page number of -1 and/or 0 might be confusing. So, set the page numbering to be `roman` instead, even though they won't be explicitly visible on the output pages:

   ```
   \pagestyle{empty}
   \pagenumbering{roman}% To avoid duplicate hyperref links to pages with same page number
   \maketitle
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \newpage
   % ...
   ```

Now the page numbers in the PDF viewer will read i and ii, instead of -1 and 0.

Comment: (1) didn't solve all issues in the original file, which was reduced to a testcases in this thread, but (2) seems to be the least painful workaround. though used **alph** for title page numbering, since **roman** already used in TOC. thank you!

Comment: @AlexShevchenko: Sure. Without a complete document that replicates the issue, it would be difficult to make other suggestions. You can also add a prefix to the page numbers for that specific portion of your document... just something that provides a unique `\thepage` value.

Comment: didn't know other Users may edit my posts here, so could accidentally discard your changes. it wasn't intentional and if so would be appreciated for fixing that. thanks for understanding.